# SFLphone 1.3.0 microphone on Ubuntu 14.04 not working

Tags: gnome, sound, alsa, microphone

I compared  the following 2 setups with original packages from the Ubuntu distributions and with

- the same headset and
- the same second telephone and
- the same telephone account data

1) SFLphone 1.0.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 Long term support with gnome-alsa-mixer 0.9.7

2) SFLphone 1.3.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 Long term support with gnome-alsa-mixer 0.9.7
Setup 1 is working in both directions speaker and microphone.
Setup 2 is not working: only the microphone of the SFLphone side is not working
I used gnome-alsa-mixer to achieve a minimum quality of the phone calls with SFLphone 1.0.2.

The `gnome-alsa-mixer` has the same version in both Ubuntu versions but the Ubuntu 14 version displays less options to change:

```
100 % Master (100 % = slider in top position)
100 % Headphone
100 % Speaker and activated mute
100 % PCM
100 % Mic (missing in Ubuntu 14)
100 % Mic Boos 
90 % Beep
70 % Capture
             activated recording (missing in Ubuntu 14)
100 % Digital
0 % internal with not activated mute (missing in Ubuntu 14)
0 % internal
```

Do you have an idea what do I have to change for using the SFLphone1.3.0 on Ubuntu 14?

Answer (score 0):

check in edit->preferences on audio tab, which audio system is selected alsa or pulseaudio. On my 14.04 lts SFLphone phone install pulseadio was selected by default and mic did not work. After changing to alsa everything works ok.